# calculate the difference between two dates in hours/minutes on working dates

Tags: pentaho, kettle

I want to calculate the difference between two dates in hours/minutes on working dates.
I didn't find a step in PDI doing that, and I dont know how to use the javascript step
reaaally need your help.

Answer (score 2):

Calculator step has plenty of date operations available.

Edit: after clarification, this is the proper solution:

Add `Modified Java Script Value` step with the following code:

```
var diff_hours = dateDiff(dateA,dateB,"hh");
var diff_minutes = dateDiff(dateA,dateB,"mi");

Alert(diff_hours);
Alert(diff_minutes);
```

... assuming `dateA` and `dateB` are your dates.

Comment: but it doesnt return the results in hours
if for example i have date1 = 2012-02-03 14:50 and date2 = 2012-02-03 18:50 it returns 0

Comment: Ahh, you are right. I thought what you need is calculate in days and multiply by 24 to get difference in hours. My bad.

Answer (score 1):

dateDiff(var1,var2,var3);

var1: Date - **The Variable with the Startdate.**

var2: Date - **The Variable with the Endate.**

var3: String - **The Type which represents the the return value:**

y - Years , m - Months, d - Days , w - Weeks, wd - Workingdays ,hh - Hours ,mi - Minutes, **ss - Seconds**

```
Alert(dateDiff(date1,date2,"ss")); //get the date diff in seconds
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this

```
    var date1 = new Date("7/11/2010");
    var date2 = new Date("12/12/2010");
    var timeDiff = Math.abs(date2.getTime() - date1.getTime());
    var diffHours = Math.ceil(timeDiff / (1000 * 3600)); 
    var diffSeconds = Math.ceil(timeDiff / 1000); 

    alert(diffHours)​;
    alert(diffSeconds)​;
```